# Email Template Link Color wont change

Tags: html, css, pug, html-email

I have an email template in Jade which contains "links", or basically strings of text with `.com` such as `www.site.com`

They are not actually enclosed in anchor tags, however when the email is sent, they appear as links. I have tried styling the font, the anchors, and put them inline or in an internal style tag, but nothing seems to work.

This is what the code looks like:

`<font color='#e64c65'>!{site}</font>`

where the site would be a string like I described earlier. I have tried changing the `font` to an `a`, but it simply removes all the styles and makes the string a regular, unstyled text.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you try inline style + important ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif inline style + !important doesn't seem to work for me either :/

Comment: If inline styles `style="place styles here"` don't work then it is client dependent. `color=""` isn't an inline style.

Comment: *Usually* email clients will wrap text, that appears to be links, in anchor tags. Rather do this yourself then declare your rules *inline* using the `style` attribute. If this doesn't work, use the `!important` declaration, if that doesn't work either, wrap the inner text within *another* arbitrary tag (like a `span`) and style that with *inline* styles, using `!important` if necessary. In my experience, the last solution always works; wrapping the inner text with an arbitrary element and styling this element over-qualifies styles of the containing anchor tag declared by the email client.

Comment: if you can also inspect the element and show us how the HTML is rendred we may help you

Comment: After following Temani's suggestion of inspecting the element, I discovered that the link was being wrapped in an anchor tag, probably because of the email client.

Thanks to both of your suggestions, I managed to achieve the expected results by using an anchor tag, and using the inline style + !important. I've tried both of those separately but forgot to try them together. Thanks for all the help, guys!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After inspecting the element, I discovered that the email client was enclosing any string that looked like a link inside anchor tags.

What I did to fix this was instead of using a wrapper tag like `font` or `span` for the url string, I enclosed it directly in anchor tags and used inline styling for the color with `!important`

My final output looks like this:

`a(href=site style={ color: '#e64e65 !important' }) !{site}`

Answer (score 0):

The font tag is deprecated:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Try to use a `<span>` or `<p>` element instead, like so:

```
<span style="color: #e64c65;">!{site}</span>
```

Comment: **I have tried styling the font, the anchors, and put them inline or in an internal style tag, but nothing seems to work.**

Comment: he says that and yet the example he provides is still <font>... doesn't hurt to write it out imo

Comment: Yes but the issue is not about `The font tag is deprecated` .. you can say this, but how can you be sure this solution will work, as the OP said in the question he already tried this.

Comment: @TemaniAfif don't agree with you. "I have tried styling the font[...]" doesn't certify he hasn't test the `span` dommmm's solution. Milestrong ? have you test ?

Comment: @GGO i understand from this `I have tried styling the font, the anchors, and put them inline or in an internal style tag` that he tried inline style with `a` tag too. And my problem with this answer is that it's simply focusing on the deprecated tag (which is true of course) but not the issue of the question. But let's see what Milestrong will say :)
We don't forget that it's not a common html site, it's email templating

Answer (score 0):

Maybe {site} is replaced by an complete a-tag, so changing font has no impact.

Try styling the a tag in css instead.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
<p style="color: #e64c65;" color='#e64c65'>!{site}</p>
```

and in the style tag write this code::

```
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}
```